# Список всех N сайтов

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные

> Список всех 171 сайтов Stack Exchange

Насколько корректна такая формулировка? По-моему, здесь что-то не так.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать такой вариант: **Список всех сайтов Stack Exchange (171 сайт)**

Правильным было бы сочетание "всех 170 сайтов", но для числа 171 такое выражение не подходит.

Из словаря:

6. в зн. сущ. только мн.: **все, всех**. **В полном составе, без исключения**;

Comment: Ваш вариант теперь [используется на сайте](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJtYd.png)!